# cannot find log files

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am not able to view the log file after a process dies (i.e. shows red color on screen)

[plan-2] process has died [pid 2803, exit code -11, cmd /home/plan __name:=plan __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/15dd5ecc-6520-11e2-b3cb-f0def116deab/plan-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/15dd5ecc-6520-11e2-b3cb-f0def116deab/plan*.log

I cannot find plan.log in the location. However I can get the logs of roslaunch, rosout and rosmaster. Do I need to enable anything?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53108/cannot-find-log-files/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-11-04**:
Hi aswin, I am facing the exact same problem, My process dies, and the developer is asking for the log file, which I cannot find. Were you able to find that file? or how didi you debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be plan-2.log or anything like plan*.log.

It could also be that there is no log file if the segmentation fault happened before any logfile was written.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-23**:
This may be the case since the fault happens within 5 seconds of launch.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-31**:
I have had several cases in which I do not have a log file. Currently I find out the fault by running ROS with GDB.